# query string error

Tags: c#, request.querystring

Why is this code throwing a `NullReferenceException`?

**Exception:**

`System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

**Code:**

```
if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["Sno"].ToString())) 
   && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["Name"].ToString())))
{
    lblBookedBy.Text = "";
    lblSno.Text = "";
}
else
{
    lblBookedBy.Text = Request.QueryString["Name"].ToString();
    lblSno.Text = Request.QueryString["Sno"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: have you checked my answer ?

Comment: ans rest of the people answered here are out of their mind right?????

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [Convert.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tostring.aspx) instead of `.ToString()` to avoid null reference exception:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["Sno"])) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Covert.ToString(Request.QueryString["Name"])))
{
    lblBookedBy.Text = "";
    lblSno.Text = "";
}
else
{
    lblBookedBy.Text =Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["Name"]);
    lblSno.Text =Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["Sno"]);
}
```

Comment: Did you rollback my change and do the exact same edit yourself? I wasn't the one that rejected the changes on my post. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend doing the following.

```
if (Request.QueryString["Sno"] == null || Request.QueryString["Name"] == null)
{
    lblBookedBy.Text = "";
    lblSno.Text = "";
}
else
{
    lblBookedBy.Text = Request.QueryString["Name"].ToString();
    lblSno.Text = Request.QueryString["Sno"].ToString();
}
```

You are most likely getting a `NullReference` in the `if` statement. This way you are sure not to encounter this, and worst case if both of the variables are instantiated, but one or more contains an empty string it will simply set the `Text` to `empty`.

Alternatively if you use `Convert.ToString` as many other suggested you can simplify the code by skipping the `if` statement.

```
lblBookedBy.Text = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["Name"]);
lblSno.Text = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["Sno"]);
```

In worst case scenario one of these will be `Null`, and will result in one of the TextBoxes to show result, while the other one is empty.

Also, assuming that `Request.QueryString` supports it, you could use [TryGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx).

Comment: it will throw an exception if `["Sno"]` and `["Name"]` will be null.

Comment: I don't see how either one of them could be null. I am not doing a `ToString` in the `if` statement.

Comment: The edit was rejected, but your solution works as well, but is not needed in my answer as it's not possible for the values to be `Null`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to cast `Request.QueryString["Sno"]` to string  while it's value is `null`

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because there is no key "Sno" or "Name" in the collection query string which results in the exception when trying to invoke .ToString() on it.

Check if Request.QueryString["Sno"] or Request.QueryString["Name"] is null, before invoking .ToString()

Comment: yes I know they are null but after this the else part should run. Why error ?

Comment: @Gaurav can you convert null to string?

Comment: Your if statement checks that they are both null (or empty) If only one of them is null, you'll see this error.  Use an or in your if test instead.

Answer (score 1):

if `Request.QueryString["Sno"]` or `Request.QueryString["Name"]` does not return any object than calling ToString will throw exception

Answer (score 1):

Remove .ToString() in null check because when query string parameter is not available you are trying to type cast null variable to string....

```
if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["Sno"]))) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Covert.ToString(Request.QueryString["Name"]))))
```